# Customize the DbContext Generator

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, entity-framework-6, t4

For a database first design, creating the `EDMX` generates the DbContext and the poco model `T4 (.tt)` template files.
I am successfully able to customize the `Model.tt` file to make it generate POCO classes with Pascal cased class names and property names and also the poco class file names in Pascal case which fits beter  with with the coding standards of the rest of my code.

The issue I am trying to tackle is, I have to edit the `Model.tt` files for every `EDMX` when I create one, rather I am trying to see if there any way to customize the tt file generator and add the code modification to it so that the pascalcasing rule gets implemented automatically when creating an `EDMX`.
I am not sure if this is possible. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize Visual Studio item templates for entity framework. Then each edmx that you add to the project using `Add New Item` window, choosing `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`, will use modified templates.

For example, for `C#` language and locale `1033` and `EF6`, The templates are stored at:

```
\VisualStudioInstallationPath\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Data\1033\DbCtxCSEF6
```

And the files are:

- `CSharpDbContext.Context.tt`
- `CSharpDbContext.Types.tt`

For more information:

- [How to: Locate and Organize Project and Item Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Reza for the valuable info and for guiding me with SO best practice.