# How can I set Entity Framework CommandTimeout in AutoGenerated Edmx file

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, entity-framework, visual-studio

We are using EF6 as DB First and the models and edmx files are generated using .tt templates.

Now we need to set command time out which is fairly straight forward

```
Partial Public Class ReservingEntities
Inherits DbContext

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New("name=ReservingEntities")
    Database.CommandTimeout = 0
End Sub
```

But the problem is everytime we update our EF from database `Database.CommandTimeout = 0` line is removed as class is constructed from template.

Can you suggest what is the right place to set the timeout so that it is persisted ?

Comment: You can edit the `T4` template and add your code there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either of these options:

- You can customize `t4` templates of your current project.
- You also can edit visual studio templates for entity framework. Then each `edmx` that you add to the project using Add New Item window, choosing ADO.NET Entity Data Model, will use modified templates.

**Customize the entity framework templates for current projet**

You can edit the `.Context.tt` template which is under `.edmx` file and add your code there.

In `VB.NET` those `.tt` files are hidden. To change them, in solution explorer toolbar click Show all files to see `.tt` files under your `.edmx` file. Then open `.Context.tt` file and add your code after this block:

```
Partial <#=Accessibility.ForType(container)#> Class <#=code.Escape(container)#>
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("name=<#=container.Name#>")
```

In `C#`, files are not hidden and you can open `.Context.tt` file and put the code after this block:

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(container)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(container)#> : DbContext
{
    public <#=code.Escape(container)#>()
        : base("name=<#=container.Name#>")
    {
```

**Customize the entity framework templates that Visual Studio use**

You can customize Visual Studio item templates for entity framework. Then each edmx that you add to the project using Add New Item window, choosing ADO.NET Entity Data Model, will use modified templates.

For example, for C# language and locale 1033 and `EF6`, you can edit `CSharpDbContext.Context.tt` file which is stored at below path:

```
\VisualStudioInstallationPath\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Data\1033\DbCtxCSEF6
```

Comment: You may also find this post helpful: [Customize the DbContext Generator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34667164/3110834). In the other post I showd how you can customize the templates that visual studio use. You can customize Visual Studio item templates for entity framework. Then each edmx that you add to the project using Add New Item window, choosing ADO.NET Entity Data Model, will use modified templates.